# pandas filtering and column boolean operation in one line possible?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to reduce to a single line the following filtering of a pandas dataframe

First an example DF:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'myfiltercol':[1,1,1,2,2],
                    'D':[True,False,True,False,True],
                    'E':[False,True,False,True,False]})

print(dff)

  myfiltercol      D      E
0            1   True  False
1            1  False   True
2            1   True  False
3            2  False   True
4            2   True  False
```

Now for the case in which myfiltercol = 1 I would like to make the boolean operation OR between column values of D and E and see if all the values are true.

I was able to it like this in two lines:

```
dff2   = dff.loc[(dff['myfiltercol'] == 1),['D','E']]
result = all(dff2['D'] | dff2['E'])
```

For some reason I need a one liner.
Someone knows how?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) instead of the *logical or* between both columns since you've already indexed on them and [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) reducing to a single boolean value:

```
dff.loc[(dff['myfiltercol'] == 1),['D','E']].any(1).all()
# True
```

Or if these are all the columns you have you could also do:

```
dff.set_index('myfiltercol').loc[1].any(1).all()
# True
```

Comment: so any(1) is doing any True in axis 1. Axis 1 should be column. The thing is, it works, but I don't know why.

Comment: So any along axis 1 is checking whether there are any Trues along the columns, so the same as `dff2['D'] | dff2['E']` @Berlines

Answer (score 1):

Would this do?:

```
>>> dff.loc[(dff['myfiltercol'] == 1),:].eval('D | E').all()
True
```